# asp.net webapi : error string cannot be convert string to http response message

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am implementing a asp.net webapi control that updates a value and returns a string to the client. Currently i am getting error string cannot be convert string to http response message

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPut]
    public HttpResponseMessage ReviewLegalFundClass(int fundClassId, int reviewTypeId)
    {
        var svc = Resolve<IUserIdentityService>();
        var user = svc.GetCurrentUser();

        try
        {
            var fcService = GetService<LEGAL_FUND_CLASS>();
            var fundClass = fcService.Get(fundClassId);
            var response = "N/A";
            var users = GetViewService<V_PERMAL_USER_ALL>().GetAll();

            if (reviewTypeId == (int)LegalFundClassReviewType.Fees)
            {
                fundClass.FEES_LAST_REVIEWED_BY_ID = user.ID;
                fundClass.FEES_LAST_REVIEWED_DATE = DateTime.Now;

                var feeUsr = users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == fundClass.FEES_LAST_REVIEWED_BY_ID);
                response = $"Last Reviewed: {feeUsr?.LOGIN_NAME} {fundClass.FEES_LAST_REVIEWED_DATE.Value.ToString(PermalConstants.DateFormat2)}";
            }
            else if (reviewTypeId == (int)LegalFundClassReviewType.Terms)
            {
                fundClass.TERMS_LAST_REVIEWED_BY_ID = user.ID;
                fundClass.TERMS_LAST_REVIEWED_DATE = DateTime.Now;

                var termsUsr = users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == fundClass.TERMS_LAST_REVIEWED_BY_ID);
                response = $"Last Reviewed: {termsUsr?.LOGIN_NAME} {fundClass.TERMS_LAST_REVIEWED_DATE.Value.ToString(PermalConstants.DateFormat2)}";
            }
            else throw new Exception("Invalid fund class review type");

            fcService.Update(fundClass);

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return GetError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're returning a string in your method: you declared your response variable as a string "N/A". so you're going to want to change your return type of 'HttpResponseMessage' to 'string'.

```
public string ReviewLegalFundClass(int fundClassId, int reviewTypeId)
```

also when you catch your exception... maybe also try

```
return ex.Message;
```

or

```
throw new Exception(ex.Message);
```

Exception.Message property is a string, so you'll be good there. or if your GetError() method returns a string, then ignore what I said haha. Good luck. Let me know how that works out for you.